# Recovering data from NTFS after SSD ran out of spare blocks

Tags: data-recovery, ntfs

I had the main SSD for a computer run out of spare blocks and thus refuse any/all write operations by Windows. This led to all the problems you'd expect, and a lot of frustration.

I've since replaced the SSD and reinstalled Windows, but now I need to recover data from that drive.

The drive is readable - all blocks can be read. The drive will refuse write operations.

I've `dd`'d all 1.8 TB from the partition (`/dev/sdb4`) to a file so I can work offline.

But now I need to recover the data.

```
[root@VintageWarlord Temporary]# mount.ntfs-3g -o force,ro sdb4.image /mnt/test
$MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 3).
Failed to mount '/home/christopher/Temporary/sdb4.image': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

(I've tried `mount.ntfs` and other iterations as well to no avail, and got the same error when trying to mount directly from the SSD).

It really, really does not like this volume. AFAIK this volume is not bitlocker encrypted.

```
[root@VintageWarlord Temporary]# hexdump -C sdb4.image | more
00000000  eb 52 90 4e 54 46 53 20  20 20 20 00 02 08 00 00  |.R.NTFS    .....|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 f8 00 00  3f 00 ff 00 00 b0 11 00  |........?.......|
00000020  00 00 00 00 80 00 80 00  f6 52 be e8 00 00 00 00  |.........R......|
00000030  00 00 0c 00 00 00 00 00  02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  f6 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  de 9f ff 0e bf ff 0e 4c  |...............L|
00000050  00 00 00 00 fa 33 c0 8e  d0 bc 00 7c fb 68 c0 07  |.....3.....|.h..|
00000060  1f 1e 68 66 00 cb 88 16  0e 00 66 81 3e 03 00 4e  |..hf......f.>..N|
00000070  54 46 53 75 15 b4 41 bb  aa 55 cd 13 72 0c 81 fb  |TFSu..A..U..r...|
00000080  55 aa 75 06 f7 c1 01 00  75 03 e9 dd 00 1e 83 ec  |U.u.....u.......|
00000090  18 68 1a 00 b4 48 8a 16  0e 00 8b f4 16 1f cd 13  |.h...H..........|
000000a0  9f 83 c4 18 9e 58 1f 72  e1 3b 06 0b 00 75 db a3  |.....X.r.;...u..|
000000b0  0f 00 c1 2e 0f 00 04 1e  5a 33 db b9 00 20 2b c8  |........Z3... +.|
000000c0  66 ff 06 11 00 03 16 0f  00 8e c2 ff 06 16 00 e8  |f...............|
000000d0  4b 00 2b c8 77 ef b8 00  bb cd 1a 66 23 c0 75 2d  |K.+.w......f#.u-|
000000e0  66 81 fb 54 43 50 41 75  24 81 f9 02 01 72 1e 16  |f..TCPAu$....r..|
000000f0  68 07 bb 16 68 52 11 16  68 09 00 66 53 66 53 66  |h...hR..h..fSfSf|
00000100  55 16 16 16 68 b8 01 66  61 0e 07 cd 1a 33 c0 bf  |U...h..fa....3..|
00000110  0a 13 b9 f6 0c fc f3 aa  e9 fe 01 90 90 66 60 1e  |.............f`.|
00000120  06 66 a1 11 00 66 03 06  1c 00 1e 66 68 00 00 00  |.f...f.....fh...|
00000130  00 66 50 06 53 68 01 00  68 10 00 b4 42 8a 16 0e  |.fP.Sh..h...B...|
00000140  00 16 1f 8b f4 cd 13 66  59 5b 5a 66 59 66 59 1f  |.......fY[ZfYfY.|
00000150  0f 82 16 00 66 ff 06 11  00 03 16 0f 00 8e c2 ff  |....f...........|
00000160  0e 16 00 75 bc 07 1f 66  61 c3 a1 f6 01 e8 09 00  |...u...fa.......|
00000170  a1 fa 01 e8 03 00 f4 eb  fd 8b f0 ac 3c 00 74 09  |............<.t.|
00000180  b4 0e bb 07 00 cd 10 eb  f2 c3 0d 0a 41 20 64 69  |............A di|
00000190  73 6b 20 72 65 61 64 20  65 72 72 6f 72 20 6f 63  |sk read error oc|
000001a0  63 75 72 72 65 64 00 0d  0a 42 4f 4f 54 4d 47 52  |curred...BOOTMGR|
000001b0  20 69 73 20 63 6f 6d 70  72 65 73 73 65 64 00 0d  | is compressed..|
000001c0  0a 50 72 65 73 73 20 43  74 72 6c 2b 41 6c 74 2b  |.Press Ctrl+Alt+|
000001d0  44 65 6c 20 74 6f 20 72  65 73 74 61 72 74 0d 0a  |Del to restart..|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 8a 01  a7 01 bf 01 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200  07 00 42 00 4f 00 4f 00  54 00 4d 00 47 00 52 00  |..B.O.O.T.M.G.R.|
00000210  04 00 24 00 49 00 33 00  30 00 00 d4 00 00 00 24  |..$.I.3.0......$|
00000220  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000250  00 00 00 00 00 00 e9 c0  00 90 05 00 4e 00 54 00  |............N.T.|
00000260  4c 00 44 00 52 00 07 00  42 00 4f 00 4f 00 54 00  |L.D.R...B.O.O.T.|
00000270  54 00 47 00 54 00 07 00  42 00 4f 00 4f 00 54 00  |T.G.T...B.O.O.T.|
00000280  4e 00 58 00 54 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |N.X.T...........|
00000290  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 0d 0a 41 6e 20 6f  |............An o|
000002a0  70 65 72 61 74 69 6e 67  20 73 79 73 74 65 6d 20  |perating system |
000002b0  77 61 73 6e 27 74 20 66  6f 75 6e 64 2e 20 54 72  |wasn't found. Tr|
000002c0  79 20 64 69 73 63 6f 6e  6e 65 63 74 69 6e 67 20  |y disconnecting |
000002d0  61 6e 79 20 64 72 69 76  65 73 20 74 68 61 74 20  |any drives that |
000002e0  64 6f 6e 27 74 0d 0a 63  6f 6e 74 61 69 6e 20 61  |don't..contain a|
000002f0  6e 20 6f 70 65 72 61 74  69 6e 67 20 73 79 73 74  |n operating syst|
00000300  65 6d 2e 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |em..............|
```

At this point I don't care about getting this drive back operational, I just want the data off of it. I could do something like `tar -xf sdb4.image .` I would absolutely do that. I don't have a 2TB drive laying around I can just image this to then run ntfsfix on then copy data off of, but I can buy one if that's what it takes.

How can I recover this data (preferably without purchasing hardware)? I have abundant storage space for storing the image or processed versions of the image, but no spare full drives I can `dd` the data back to.

Comment: [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1144611/432690) is old, but AFAIK Linux is still not well equipped to fix NTFS. `chkdsk` in Windows may be the best you can do. It will probably require a writable block device (I mean it probably won't work with the regular file you have). So either you write the image to a healthy block device and let Windows handle it, or you connect (a copy of) the image as a virtual block device to a virtual machine and let virtual Windows handle it. *Maybe* you will need to create a partition table (to avoid [this](https://superuser.com/q/1060252/432690)).

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to purchase a new disk. Spinning metal if you like, but around 3TB-4TB. First of all, use it with `ddrescue` to build a disk image that can be corrected with a Windows system. Then once you've done that and retrieved the lost data, repurpose it for taking regular backups.